# Get concatened string from variable in javascript object with map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have this object below:

```
var products = [
        {
           "id":"xxx",
           "name":"AAA"
        },
        {
           "id":"xxx",
           "name":"BBB"
        }
     ];
```

I´m trying to mapping the object and generate a concatenated string from all the values ´name´ using the map function and then join to concatenate the comma:

```
var result = products.map(p => Object.values(p.name).join(','));
```

But I'm getting this output with console.log:

"A,A,A, ,B,B,B"

The is one more comma there and plus it takes each character instead of the full key name value.
Am I not accessing the array object in the right way?

Comment: You're calling `Object.values()` each name string, instead you want to just map the `name` properties, and then call join on the result of the map. `var result = products.map(p => p.name).join(', ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're turning a string into an array and joining each character with a comma between them. You need to move the join outside of the map iterator function. There is also no need for the Object.value() call.

```
const result = products
  .map((product) => product.name)
  .join(', ')
```

```js
var products = [
  {
     "id":"xxx",
     "name":"AAA"
  },
  {
     "id":"xxx",
     "name":"BBB"
  }
];

const result = products.map((product) => product.name).join(', ')

document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your questions but i guess you're trying to concatenate the name values .If Yes,use the below code.

```
var result = products.map(p => Object.values(p.name).join('')).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map` and `Array.join`

Logic

- Create a list of names from `products` using `Array.map`.
- From that list create a string with `Array.join`

```js
var products = [{"id":"xxx","name":"AAA"},{"id":"xxx","name":"BBB"}];
console.log(products.map(item => item.name).join(','))
```